# Anonymous JQuery parse request in network debugger

Tags: jquery, angularjs, laravel, nginx

Would like to check if anyone knows what is the problem or what is causing it that I have multiple parse request executed by jQuery when any form of action is being executed in almost every page? This is annoying because it slows down the website's performance.

Note that I am using `jQuery 2.1.4` with `angularJS 1.3.15` in `laravel 5` framework behind `nginx`

[image: JQUERY]

Comment: show more details about this `parse` POST request, its headers, and response headers?

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers i managed to found the problem. Pls see my answer. Thanks for the pro tip of analyzing the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After analyzing the request header, I realized that the request was made from Skype's "Click to call" function

[image: skype]

`/skypectoc/v1/pnr/parse` it's called by the Skype Plugin (installed on chrome) thats why you see that XHR call only in google chrome.

Simply disable the function or uninstall if not used.